# Attempt at foreground image not working

Tags: html, css

I need a page that has an image overlapping the entire page. I have this code right now but my image is just being appended to the bottom.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

## HTML Code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/themes/txt/css/record_keeper/training_report.css" />
  </head>

  <body style="position:relative;">
    <div class="content">
       <p>Content here</p>
    </div>
    <img src="/media/images/record_keeper/lines.jpg" style="z-index:10; position:relative;">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an image showing what you need?

Comment: `position: absolute`? What rules do you have in your CSS file?

Comment: @HaukurHaf I don't have an image for an example, but I literally want a picture that sits on top of body.

Comment: @putvande Tried that and it's still being appended to the bottom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have that image right on top, you need to use `position: absolute`, and give it some `top`, `left` etc options.:

```
<img src="/media/images/record_keeper/lines.jpg" style="z-index:10; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;">
```

Comment: +1 and `position:relative` on body is redundant here.

Comment: So I tried it out and it worked. I'm using this page within a Django application that renders html into a pdf, and unfortunately it doesn't render in that properly but I guess that's a whole new problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe the PDF renderer doesn't support all CSS styles? What renderer is it?

Comment: Yeah, looks like that might be the case. I'm using [Django easy-pdf](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-easy-pdf)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution using pure CSS is:

This will create a foreground div with a background image.

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
    <p>Content here</p>
</div>

<div class="MyImg"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.MyImg{
    background: #eee url(http://www.socialtalent.co/wp-content/uploads/blog-content/so-logo.png) center center no-repeat;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

### CLICK FOR DEMO

Comment: Pure css? You mean instead of just using an `img` tag?

Comment: Yes. I am not undermining your answer, just providing an alternative. There are many good reason to use css images rather than hard coded on the page. It's arguably more efficient, faster and cleaner on your code. Just depends how many image tags you have on the website.

Answer (score -1):

You can try adding a div tag around the body:

```
    <div id=wrapper>
        <body>
            *content goes here*
        </body>
    </div>
```

then on your CSS:

```
    #wrapper {
         background-image:url('/media/images/record_keeper/lines.jpg');
    }
```

Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a **background**-image, OP wants a **foreground**-image. Also, you can't have a `body` tag there.